# How to update a total field after updating an element in an array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of objects where each object has a `count` value. Is it possible to update a `total` field without `$sum`ing all the values after one of the values has changed?

For example, given the following data

```
{
    "elements": [
        {"id": "A", "count": 1},
        {"id": "B", "count": 2},
        {"id": "C", "count": 3},
    ],
    
    "total": 6
}
```

I want to update object A's `count` to `2` and `total` to `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to handle this situation, you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `elements` and update `count` when condition `id` match
- update total by `$sum` of count

```
db.collection.update({
  "elements.id": "B"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      elements: {
        $map: {
          input: "$elements",
          in: {
            id: "$$this.id",
            count: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.id", "A"] },
                2,
                "$$this.count"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $set: { total: { $sum: "$elements.count" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BrmHih82Gmy)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would stronget suggest you to use Mongoose in your project, as it will provide pretty powerfull tools to access the information contained in your MongoDB. For example, the easiest to get a dynamically updated total would be turning this field into a virtual one:

```
YourSchema.virtual("total").get(function () {
    this.elements.map(element => element.count).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
});
```

If you need the field not to be virtual, I would suggest using Mongoose's middleware YourSchema.pre("save") to update the total field each time an entry from this collection is modified.

```
YourSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    this.total = this.elements.map(element => element.count).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
    next();
});
```